# Trying to install gearman on CentOS, and ./configure cannot find event.h even though libevent is installed

Tags: centos

I'm trying to compile and install [gearman](http://gearman.org) onto a CentOS 6 box, and am getting an error when I compile from its source code.  It requires the boost libraries, and was failing on that at first, but I installed those and it gets past that. Now, however, when I run ./configure it is failing with the message:

```
. . .
checking for ld that supports -Wl,-z,relro... yes
checking event.h usability... no
checking event.h presence... no
checking for event.h... no
configure: error: Unable to find libevent
```

So I installed libevent like so:

```
yum install libevent.i686
```

And that didn't help.  So I downloaded the source to my home directory, extracted it to a sub directory within my home directory, ran `./configure` and then `make install` and then tried `./configure` on the gearman source, but it still gives me the `configure: error: Unable to find libevent` message.  You can imagine how annoying that is!  Especially after I tried installing libevent via yum and then installed it from source.

Any tips to get gearman ./configure to get past this message?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `libevent-devel` for the development files.